# What should I use for a smooth surface wall board for quilting layout?

Tags: drywall, materials, backer-board

For purposes of laying out a quilting project, I want to use an approx 4' by 7' wall space.  I have a large piece of thin fabric that is tacky on both sides.  One side goes against the wall and stays there.  On the other side, I place small blocks of fabric for a quilt, rearranging them until I've found a pleasing layout.

The tacky fabric needs a smooth wall surface.  My painted and textured wallboard is not smooth enough.  I could use additional spray glue, but I don't want to spray that on the wall, as it may be difficult to clean up when I want restore the wall to its original condition.

I think the solution is to mount another board on the wall, attached with appropriate anchors.  I could put up gypsum board/drywall, but what other board type would be better?  Something really smooth and thin would be best.

Comment: Why not just sand the texture down and repaint, cheaper and easier than putting more material on the walls. at my last home I had a huge projection wall that was glass smooth with the glass beads in the paint. Around the outside I put some trim it looked like a giant picture frame.  You could do the same using a gloss paint that would hold the sticky fabric.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to permanently change that wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obtain a [4'x8' piece of coated hardboard](https://www.google.com/search?q=white+hardboard&oq=white+hardboard) and hang that on the wall. (You could also build a frame for around it as Ed Beal suggested in his comment.)

The hardboard has a smooth, white, glossy acrylic surface for the tack cloth to stick to, and is thin enough to still be lightweight.

You can pick one up at a BigBox store for about $20.

Comment: Some hardboard comes in brown but is still very smooth. (Just in case OP can't find white, the brown stuff should work, too.)

Comment: True. The brown stuff doesn't have the same surface coating though and that coating might be a good idea for moisture resistance and durability, etc. I think you're right tho. the brown should work too.

Comment: Terrific. Just the kind of response I was hoping for: a specific kind of product that I was pretty sure existed but didn't know how to search for"  "smooth wall board" didn't get it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A sheet of plywood either 3 or 5 ply would work.

Have to fill screw holes after though.